# Use clause in for repeating data - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a hash table:

```
table: hash
hash_id hash
'1', 'xKsKoM'
'2', 'taahmD'
'3', '23PNiJa'
```

When you run the query:

```
select * 
from 
where hash in ('taahmD', 'taahmD')
```

This results (one line): 
    1. taahmD

But I need to return (two line, ... nlines): 
    1. taahmD 
    2. taahmD

It is only returned a row - needed to return two (duplicate).

What is the solution?

Comment: Given your sample data, why should it return 2 results?  Your `where` criteria is equivalent to `where hash = 'taahmD'`...

Comment: Needed to return duplicate, but because of the values within the same in only returns one row. It would be the case using union all?

Answer (score 0):

For example you may join some table with two values. (Edited add word INNER )

```
select t.* 
from <your table> t
INNER JOIN (select 1 as a from dual 
      union all
      select 2 as a from dual) d on 1=1
where hash in ('taahmD')
```

Or request table twice

```
select t.* 
from <your table> t
where hash in ('taahmD')
union all 
select t.* 
from <your table> t
where hash in ('taahmD')
```

Comment: thanks ... I would like using the first form repeating different times for different hashes? so I tried but did not work:

` select h. *
from hash h
JOIN (select 1 from dual to the
       union all
       select 2 from the the dual) d on 1 = 1 and hash in ('taahmD')
JOIN (select 1 from dual to b) and on 1 = 1 and hash in ('23PNiJa')`

Comment: Thank you for correction. As I know in MySQL you should write INNER JOIN insted of JOIN. I correct first query.

Comment: Why you write "JOIN (select 1 from dual to b) and on 1 = 1 and hash in ('23PNiJa')"? It does not make sense

Comment: Because I need to repeat several hashes, not one.

Answer (score 0):

> But I need to return (two line, ... nlines)

You could use union, but for `n` lines it would be cumbersome, the other way is to join simple hierarchical query generating `n` rows. Here is the example for 5 rows (Oracle version):

```
select hash
  from hash cross join (select null from dual connect by level <= 5)
  where hash = 'taahmD'
```